# Laravel 4.1 - Error messages stays for next requests

Tags: php, session, redirect, laravel, response

I'm sending errors that appear in validation process like this:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($article->errors());
```

and retrieving them in view. Normally when I was doing it in admin panel where user was logged in , errors appear once and during the next request there MessageBag doesn't contain them.

But now I'm trying do this same for non logged user on the main page and MessageBag is not empty after a new request.

Any idea what could be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: withErrors should only flash the errors to the Session, only staying for the first request. It's odd it doesn't behave like that here. Could you put up a bit more of your code? A comparison between your admin and non-admin part perhaps?

Comment: I check differences in routes, controllers and even filters. Nothing work, now I'm checking views and probably I fund a problem in blade template where in scripts section where is \@show instead \@parent... but how that can break flash messages I don't know.

Comment: I don't think your blade template can have any influence on this. Only thing I can think of is that you have a reflash() somewhere in your code. You might want to update your post with more code, would make it easier to look for the solution.

Comment: same for me the error stays for endless http requests. So does input::old(). I don't know why this is the case

Answer (score 0):

The problem fixed was fixed.

I set up my blade file like this:

```
@extends('site.layouts.default')
@section('stylesfiles')
{{ Basset::show('file_upload.css') }}
@endsection
@section('content')
@stop

@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
...some js
</script>

@show
@stop
```

Only thing I must do to stop that error was delete line with

```
@show
```

You can think it's because it gives some code to site, but it don't I check source of site with it and without and it was the same don't counting some additional spaces.

*I moved this answer from the posted question into a community wiki.*